# Free shipping message bar for M2

Tags: magento-2.1, magento2.2.2, free-shipping

I have tried so many times to create a simple way by creating CMS block to show the "Free Shipping Eligible Message for Adding Certain Amount in Cart" but I didn't get it yet.

Could you please help me out how I can show the Free Shipping Eligible Message on Checkout Page in top. Please check my images and please give the clear instruction with files and code here.

[image]

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Do you want to show it in shopping cart page only?

Comment: I want to show the message for Free shipping Like: Customer Added 1 items for $50 but the customer will she the top bar a message where customer can see the message Like: "You will get Free Shipping After adding $100.0 price" if your cart. If Customer add $50.0 worth item then Message will show like: "Just remaining $50.0 to get Free Shipping"

Comment: This method its works on magento 2.3.3 ?¿? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add free shipping notification on without creating module too ( if someone wishes ) using bit of knockout.js and web/html template.

Like, Code 'written below', on checkout page, will check if current store is US and total is < 1500 then will show shipping message under your cart summary block, so you can use that logic and technique to apply where you want.

Step 1 - Copy below files from vendor magento-checkout module:

`/vendor/magento/module-checkout/web/js/view/summary/cart-items.js`
`/vendor/magento/module-checkout/web/template/summary/cart-items.html`

To :

`/package/customtheme/Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/summary/cart-items.js`
`/package/customtheme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/summary/cart-items.html`

in your themes's **cart-items.js** file add below function / code ( you can change as per your requirements ) :

```
/**
     * Get Order total on checkout page sidebar
     * @returns {boolean}
     */
    getOrderTotal: function(){
        var totals = quote.getTotals()();

        var storeCode = quote.getStoreCode();

        if (totals['grand_total'] < 1500 && storeCode == 'us') {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
        /*
        if (totals) {
            return totals['grand_total'];
        }

        return quote['grand_total'];*/
    }
```

And in your theme's **cart-items.html** file add below block :

```
<div class="free-shipping-block">
    <!-- ko if: getOrderTotal() -->
    <span>You can avail FREE SHIPPING on Order Total of Rs. 1500/-<br>
    <a class="action viewcart" data-bind="attr: {href: cartUrl}">
        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Continue Shopping'"></span>
    </a></span>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

This will give you little guidance how to do using, js and html.

Answer (score 3):

Create a module with name **STech_Freeshipping** and create the files like below steps:

**Step 1:**
Create **registration.php** under:

> app/code/STech/Freeshipping/registration.php

with below content:

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'STech_Freeshipping',
    __DIR__
);
```

**Step 2:**
Create **module.xml** under:

> app/code/STech/Freeshipping/etc/module.xml

with below content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="STech_Freeshipping" setup_version="0.0.1">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Backend"/>
            <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**Step 3:**
Create **Freeshipping.php** under:

> app/code/STech/Freeshipping/Block/Freeshipping.php

with below content:

```
<?php
namespace STech\Freeshipping\Block;

class Freeshipping extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_scopeConfig;

    protected $_cart;    

    protected $_checkoutSession;

    protected $_priceHelper;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data $priceHelper,
        array $data = []
    ){
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->_cart = $cart;
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->_priceHelper = $priceHelper;
        parent::__construct($context,$data);
    }

    public function isEligible(){
        if($this->isEnable() && ($this->getSubtotal() >= $this->getFreeshippingAmount())){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function getMessage(){
        if($this->isEnable()){
            $subTotal = $this->getSubtotal();
            $freeshippingAmount = $this->getFreeshippingAmount();
            if($subTotal >= $freeshippingAmount){
                $message = __('Congratulation! Your order will be shipped for free');
            }
            else{
                $amount = $freeshippingAmount - $subTotal;
                $message = __('Just remaining %1 to get Free Shipping', $this->_priceHelper->currency($amount, true, false));
            }
            return $message;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function getSubtotal(){
        return $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getSubtotal();
    }

    public function getGrandtotal(){
        return $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getGrandTotal();
    }

    public function isEnable(){
        return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('carriers/freeshipping/active', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
    }

    public function getFreeshippingAmount(){
        return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('carriers/freeshipping/free_shipping_subtotal', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
    }
}
```

**Step 4:**
Create **checkout_cart_index.xml** under:

> app/code/STech/Freeshipping/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml

with below content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="main.content">
            <block class="STech\Freeshipping\Block\Freeshipping" name="freeshipping.message" before="-" template="STech_Freeshipping::freeshipping.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Step 5:**
Create **freeshipping.phtml** under:

> app/code/STech/Freeshipping/view/frontend/templates/freeshipping.phtml

with below content:

```
<p><?= $block->getMessage() ?></p>
```

Run setup upgrade, di compile and other required commands and test.

Comment: Is it working fine?

Comment: I am just created the Module now I am going to check. If I face any issue I will let you know

Comment: It's not showing any message on View Edit Cart Page. 
My message bar will calculate the X amount when customer will add X amount Items If the Customer don't Add X amount then the Message will show X amount left for free shipping

Comment: Need to edit the code then. Currently if you reach or eligible for free shipping then message will show. I ll update my code tomorrow.

Comment: Hi Dear Did you update your code?

Comment: I have updated my answer. I have added one more function in my block class and also update the phtml content. Please check and let me know.

Comment: I have updated the block file again to show currency symbol for remaining amount. Check and let me know.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
I will let you know after the testing

Comment: app/code/STech/Freeshipping/view/frontend/templates/freeshipping.phtml
Just need to add " <p><?= $block->getMessage() ?></p> "

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: No Issue. I just Asked you to add only that single code by removing before what I have used in freeshipping.phtml file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83104/discussion-between-sukumar-gorai-and-shakib-rahman).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the following extension because it does exactly what you are looking for and much more.

You can show different free shipping banner based on shipping country, customer group, grand total, date ranges and many more

[Magento 2 Free Shipping Bar](https://www.scommerce-mage.com/magento-2-free-shipping-bar.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can show it as a Banner.

1. Create a Banner , and the Widget as Banner Rotator , where to display the Banner.
2. In the Content of the Banner you should call the Block and template.
3. Create the template and assign it to the block.